# How create barcode image using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

I want to create a barcode image, from an employee record using C#.

Comment: What is employee record? Provide please more details...

Comment: Question too vague. Expand or close it, or maybe just ask about how to create a barcode. And, by the way, what does Javascript have to do with C# and barcodes?

Comment: If that is your final answer, @Sergey, there is no need to put up this Q & A website, isn't there.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear question to me. I don't see why this was closed.

Answer (score 11):

Here's some code I used for a recent project. It requires you downloading and installing the barcode font code39.

```
    private static void CreateBarcode(string code)
    {
        var myBitmap = new Bitmap(500,50);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
        var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        g.Clear(Color.White);

        var strFormat = new StringFormat {Alignment = StringAlignment.Center};
        g.DrawString(code, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 50), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 50), strFormat);

        var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        myBitmap.Save(@"c:\Barcode.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (var codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I plugged the code in as it is, gives `A generic error occurred in GDI+.` exception. And I am pretty sure font is installed

Comment: @jaminator, which line causes you a problem?

Comment: My bad, It was not the code, its asp.net not having permission to write a file; now I am just doing response.write that image

Comment: I am not able to scan the barcodes printed with the above logic. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

[C# Barcode Generator WebService](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/wsbarcode.aspx)

[Creating EAN-13 Barcodes with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ean_13_barcodes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A barcode is really just a font.  If you use a barcode font and provide a valid text value, the barcode will render correctly.

The barcode that I've had the most experience with is the [3 of 9 barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39).  It had encodings for 0-9, A-Z and a few other characters.  If you have the font for this barcode, you simply render the text (e.g. 'abc123') in that font and it will be encoded. There's nothing else to do!

The question needs more information to determine how you are using the barcode.